# How to check if touchevent exists using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to get rid off the error "referenceError: can't find variable TouchEvent" on safari browser. My code is as below,

```
function copy_mouse_event(event) {
    const event_init = {
    // EventInit
    bubbles: event.bubbles,
    eventPhase: event.eventPhase,

    // UIEventInit
    detail: event.detail,
    view: event.view,

    // EventModifierInit
    altKey: event.altKey,
    ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey
  };

  // initialise MouseEvent data which is shared by wheel, mouse and pointer events
  let mouse_event_init = {};
  if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
      mouse_event_init = {
          ...event_init,
          button: event.button,
          buttons: event.buttons,
          clientX: event.clientX,
          clientY: event.clientY,
          relatedTarget: event.relatedTarget,
          screenX: event.screenX,
          screenY: event.screenY
      };

      if (event instanceof WheelEvent) {
          const wheel_event_init = {
              ...mouse_event_init,
              deltaMode: event.deltaMode,
              deltaX: event.deltaX,
              deltaY: event.deltaY,
              deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
              wheelDelta: event.wheelDelta,
              wheelDeltaX: event.wheelDeltaX,
              wheelDeltaY: event.wheelDeltaY
          };
          return new WheelEvent(event.type, wheel_event_init);
      }
  }

  // try the modern pointer event first, then mouse and touch events
  if (event instanceof PointerEvent) {
      const pointer_event_init = {
          ...mouse_event_init,
          pointerId: event.pointerId,
          width: event.width,
          height: event.height,
      };
      return new PointerEvent(event.type, pointer_event_init);
  } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
      return new MouseEvent(event.type, mouse_event_init);
  } else if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {
     //error occurs here only on safari
     const touch_event_init = {
         ...event_init,
         changedTouches: event.changedTouches,
         targetTouches: event.targetTouches,
         touches: event.touches
     };
     return new TouchEvent(event.type, touch_event_init);
 }
}
```

Since safari browser doesnt support touch event, i was thinking to fix by checking if touchevent exists. How can i check if touchevent exists or not. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the existence of `TouchEvent`, you can do:

```
if ('TouchEvent' in window) {
   ...
}
```

Just checking for `TouchEvent`, as in `if (TouchEvent ...)` won't work, as if it is not defined, you'll get a runtime error. The valid way to do this would be:

```
 if (window.TouchEvent) {
     ...
 }
```

EDITED: If you want to use `typeof`, you can do it like this:

```
if (typeof TouchEvent !== 'undefined') {
    ...
}
```

Use the approach you prefer, as both work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i use typeof operator to check if touchevent defined and how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by having this check for [***interaction media features***](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-any-pointer):

```
if(window.matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)").matches) {
    // touchscreen
}
```